# Rails link_to_modal, need to add scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using the gems...

```
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'jquery-modal-rails'
```

In my view I have...

```
<%= link_to_modal "Add Exsisting Shot", add_shots_path %>
```

I am using this modal window to list a bunch of objects. These objects list out of the windows if I have more than a few. How can I add a scroll bar to this window. I found overflow:auto and am trying to do something like...

```
<%= link_to_modal "Add Exsisting Shot", add_shots_path, overflow:auto %>
```

...but rails no likey.

Answer (score 1):

Associating the class with the link did not work. But wrapping my view in the appropriate class did. Here is my code...

## app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
.classname{
 max-height: 400px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

## app/views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_modal "Modal", new_task_path %>
```

## app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="classname">
  ...contents of view here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in a css file

```
.classname{
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Then in the view, update the link_to_modal as

```
<%= link_to_modal "Add Exsisting Shot", add_shots_path, class: "classname" %>
```

Comment: Good call, this makes total sense, but it not working for me. I'm inspecting the element, and not seeing the overflow in the css. Will continue digging.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. See what worked for me below.